# Manipulating Images using jQuery (or other library)

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, image-manipulation

I'm searching for a plugin, library or just a custom JS function that will enable the manipulation of images so that they look like they're winding around a roll of paper.

If it's hard to imagine, think of a paper towel roll standing up spinning. I already know of jQuery Roundabout but that only moves the images. I need them to actually be distorted as they roll around. I can't seem to find anything of the sort.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure of any plugin that does that, but I'd recommend learning about the [`canvas`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/canvas) element and its JavaScript API.